# Elegant way to Extend Enums

Tags: java

I have a requirement that is close to extending enums and since that is not possible, after doing some research online, I came up with this approach of using interfaces and making the enums extend them.

My problem is that I have a few basic types A,B and a flag for each type that says if that has to be checked. Similarly I have some extended types C... which do the same stuff after checking their flags.

Here is the code that does this

Type Interface:

```
public interface Type {

    public String name();

}
```

Here is the class that uses the basic types

```
public class BasicChecker {

    private static boolean checkA = false;
    private static boolean checkB = false;

    public enum BasicType implements Type {
        A, B;
    }

    public static boolean isCheckA() {
        return checkA;
    }

    public static void setCheckA(boolean checkA) {
        BasicChecker.checkA = checkA;
    }

    public static boolean isCheckB() {
        return checkB;
    }

    public static void setCheckB(boolean checkB) {
        BasicChecker.checkB = checkB;
    }

    public static void doStuff(String message, Type type) {
        if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicType.A.name())) {
            doStuff(message, isCheckA());
        } else if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(BasicType.B.name())) {
            doStuff(message, isCheckB());
        }
    }

    protected static void doStuff(String message, boolean flag) {
        if (someCheckMethod() && flag) {
            doStuff(message, flag);
        }
    }

    private static boolean someCheckMethod() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the class that uses extended types

```
public class ExtendedChecker extends BasicChecker {

    private static boolean checkC = false;

    public enum ExtendedType implements Type {
        C;
    }

    public static boolean isCheckC() {
        return checkC;
    }

    public static void setCheckC(boolean checkC) {
        ExtendedChecker.checkC = checkC;
    }

    public static void doStuff(String message, Type type) {
        BasicChecker.doStuff(message, type);
        if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(ExtendedType.C.name())) {
            doStuff(message, isCheckC());
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to solve now is to remove all the if else cases from log method. I am also trying to see if there is a better way to do this. Please ignore the statics. I do want them to be static fields and methods.

Comment: `name ()` isn't overridden in the enum classes. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do from your description, but you may find `abstract` methods in `enum`s to be useful.

For example, you could add an `abstract` method "foo" to your `enum`s:

```
public enum BasicType implements Type {
    A {
        public void foo(String message) {
            // Do special A stuff
        } 
    }, B {
        public void foo(String message) {
            // Do special B stuff
        } 
    };

    public abstract void foo(String message);
}
```

And you could then use that method like this:

```
public static void doStuff(String message, Type type) {
    type.foo(message);
}
```

Naturally, you could put any such `abstract` methods in an `interface` you `extend`, if that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BasicChecker {
  private static final Set<Type> _doCheck = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Type,Boolean>());

  public enum BasicType implements Type {
    A, B;
  }

  public static boolean isCheck(Type type) {
    return return _doCheck.contains(type);
  }

  public static void setCheck(Type type, boolean check) {
    if(check) {
      _doCheck.add(type);
    } else {
      _doCheck.remove(type);
    }
  }

  public static void doStuff(String message, Type type) {
    doStuff(message, isCheck(type));
  }
}
```